# Converting ArcMap Cartographic Representations to ArcGIS Pro and exporting stylx

Tags: arcgis-pro, style, representation

Here I have a Feature Class named ContactsAndFaults, which I have imported into ArcGIS Pro from a File Geodatabase (you can find this same geodatabase [here](http://hdl.handle.net/10150/631073) if you want to reproduce this analysis). The geodatabase was created in ArcMap and Cartographic Representations (CartoReps) were used for the styling. CartoReps are not supported in ArcGIS Pro. However, you can draw your symbology from CartoReps by using **Appearances -> Symbology ->  Symbolize Your Layer Using Representations**.

[image]

This works and correctly renders the lines (you can see the difference by comparing the pictured screen shots as some lines have now become dashed etc.) It does this by converting the CartoReps to Unique Values.

[image]

Now, would like to BATCH export this styling information as an ArcGIS Pro .stylx file, but how do we do this?

Comment: You mention domains in your title but not in your question body. Did you mean to say Cartographic Representations instead?

Comment: Yes, quite sorry. Will change to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there isn't a way to do this in Pro or Python as there is an open idea on Geonet: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/arcgis-pro-quot-export-map-styles-quot-for-bulk-saving-of/idi-p/937605

Maybe vote for the idea and we may get it.

The other option is to save to Layer files and use 'ApplySymbologyFromLayer"

Comment: Thanks for the link. Good to get confirmation there is no way to do this through the ArcPro UI. Is it possible that it could be done through arcpy or some other script?